# Changing Paragraph Text OnChange of Option In Selector - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my paragraph to update depending on which option has been selected, without using a submit button. So I'm currently trying to do it with the `onchange` event. But I'm not getting anywhere, does anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

```js
function selectR() {
  document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = 'You Currently Have "RED" Selected!';
}

function selectG() {
  document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = 'You Currently Have "GREEN" Selected!';
}

function selectB() {
  document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = 'You Currently Have "BLUE" Selected!';
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option onchange="selectR()">Red</option>
  <option onchange="selectG()">Green</option>
  <option onchange="selectB()">Blue</option>
</select>

<p id="p">You Currently Have "RED" Selected!
  <p>
```

Comment: I think the event is triggered on the `select`, not the `option`, but I'm not sure about that...

Comment: Place the onchange event on the select element, when it fires, get the selected option and change your innerHTML

Comment: @MattHutch I added an answer for you below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple approach:

```js
function onChangeSelectColour() {
    var colourValue = document.getElementById("colourSelect");
    var colourIndex = colourValue.options[colourValue.selectedIndex].value;
    var colourMessage = '';

    if (colourIndex == 1)
        colourMessage = 'You Currently Have "RED" Selected!';
    else if (colourIndex == 2)
        colourMessage = 'You Currently Have "GREEN" Selected!';
    else if (colourIndex == 3)
        colourMessage = 'You Currently Have "BLUE" Selected!';

   document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = colourMessage;
}
```

```html
<select id="colourSelect" onchange="onChangeSelectColour()">
  <option value="1">Red</option>
  <option value="2">Green</option>
  <option value="3">Blue</option>
</select>

<p id="p">You Currently Have "RED" Selected!<p>
```

Comment: While this solution will work, if you ever add or remove an option from the drop down this may not work as you are hard coding the index with the color. I believe checking the selected option's text is a better solution. –

Comment: @RyanWilson that is a very fair point, I've updated my code to reflect a value within my option to search by instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Add an id value to your select, set the function call to the select onchange event
<select id="ddlMySelect" onchange="selectChange();">
  <option>Red</option>
  <option>Green</option>
  <option>Blue</option>
</select>

function selectChange() {
     // Grab your select element
     const selectElement = document.getElementById('ddlMySelect');

     // Get the text value of the selected option
     const selectedText = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].text;

     // Logic to change your paragraph text, this is actually over kill
     // Just replace the text with the option text, see below comments
     document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = 'You Currently Have ' + selectedText + ' Selected!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function selected(){
 var index = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
    switch(index) {
     case 0:
         document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = 'You Currently Have "RED" Selected!';
            break;
        case 1:
         document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = 'You Currently Have "GREEN" Selected!';
            break;
       case 2:
         document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = 'You Currently Have "BLUE" Selected!';
            break;
         
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="selected()">
  <option onchange="selectR()">Red</option>
  <option onchange="selectG()">Green</option>
  <option onchange="selectB()">Blue</option>
</select>

<p id="p">You Currently Have "RED" Selected!
  </p>
```

Comment: While this solution will work, if you ever add or remove an option from the drop down this may not work as you are hard coding the index with the color. I believe checking the selected option's text is a better solution.

Comment: I think the best way would be to add a value to each option and using that

Answer (score 0):

You could also build it in a dynamic manner and then you wouldn't even have to worry about the if's and else's. Something like this:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('select'),
    color  = document.getElementById('color');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
 var selected = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
 color.innerHTML = selected;
});
```

```html
<select id='select'>
  <option defualt>Color</option>
  <option value='red'>Red</option>
  <option value='green'>Green</option>
  <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
</select>
    
<p id="p">You Currently Have <span id='color'></span> Selected!<p>
```